# Consumo webservice com erro: unsupported content type

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-service, token-ajax

Minha primeira dúvida é:
Eu posso chamar o *WebService* diretamente via *JQUERY / AJAX* ou eu preciso ter algo em *PHP* ou alguma outra linguagem back-end para realizar a integração?

Caso seja possível somente com *JQUERY / AJAX*, segue o problema.

Eu tenho o seguinte *WebService*:

```
http://IP:PORTA/wsexecbo/WebServiceExecBO?wsdl
```

e nesse *WebService* eu tenho a seguinte função:

```
http://IP:PORTA/wsexecbo/WebServiceExecBO?wsdl/userLogin
```

que eu envio um usuário (sem senha) e ele me devolve um token.

Segue meus *custom.js*:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var soapMessage = 
  "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>" +
  "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ser='http://service.execbo.ws.framework.totvs.com'>" +
      "<soapenv:Header/>" +
      "<soapenv:Body>" +
      "<ser:userLogin>" +
      "<arg0>user</arg0>" +
      "</ser:userLogin>" +
      "</soapenv:Body>" +
  "</soapenv:Envelope>";

  var wsUrl = "http://IP:PORTA/wsexecbo/WebServiceExecBO?wsdl/userLogin";
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "xml",
      url: wsUrl,
      data: soapMessage,
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
  });
});
```

Porem sempre retorna isso:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <env:Header>
    </env:Header>
        <env:Body>
            <env:Fault xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
            <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>
                Unsupported content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
            </faultstring>
            </env:Fault>
        </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Fiz alguns testes colocando essas opções:

```
contentType: "text/xml"
contentType: "application/xml"
```

Porem nada resolve. Alguém saberia o que está acontecendo e como posso resolver isso?

Comment: o problema está no body da requisição, tenta dar um console.log no `soapMessage ` e verifica se está certinho.

Comment: Aparentemente o soapMessage está ok. Segue foto do console: https://i.imgur.com/g1LAHnz.jpg